# Adding href attribute to bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make it so that my button will open a url in a new tab.

I can get it to work using window.location.href, but the url doesn't open in a new tab that way.

I'm using jQuery and Javascript, and the code itself is inside of a larger jQuery function.

```
$('#code').click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'
});
```

The button has no href attribute on page load.

```
<button id="code" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:400px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Generate Code</button>
```

I've tried using .attr and .prop though it hasn't worked either. I'm kinda new to this stuff so I could've just done something wrong.

I'm open to either adding an href to the button or using the .click function or whatever, I just need to get this to open to a new tab.

Edit::
Ok, more explanation.

On Page load, the button onclick starts a timer that increments a progressbar. After the progressbar is done I want the button to open a link.

Comment: why not just make an anchor tag a button by using the `btn` css class. Then just use `target="_blank"` attribute.

Comment: JavaScript is a great tool, but you should avoid it where it's not necessary. Use `<a href="..." class="btn">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will open the url in a new window:

```
$('#code').click(function(){
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why, but when I was using the open function it wouldn't work. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 15):

You could do this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" id="code" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:400px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Generate Code</a>
```

I converted the `button` to an `a` tag and added `target="_blank"` to open the link in a new tab.